# How to concat javascript function name?

Tags: javascript

> Concatenate JavaScript function name

this is not working:

```
"getlatestmsg"+userid(userid, username);
```

Comment: What result are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: Dynamic function names? Bad idea.

Comment: So you have separately named functions for each user, all 10,000 of them? Where did they come from? Show us more context, and perhaps someone can offer a better approach.

Comment: One more plz.... have u know how to kill or stop periodically JavaScript calling function ?

Comment: Post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this:

window["getlatestmsg" + userid](userid, username);

Comment: Great..dude...! Working Proper

Answer (score 0):

This is bad design practice.

Instead, pass the variable to the function and then use if-else in the function

```
function myFunction(myvar){
  if (myvar==='one'){
    //logic
  }

  if (myvar==='two'){
    //logic
  } 
}
```

Comment: i have multiple function like getlatestmsg2, getlatestmsg3    2 and 3 are userid   so now i want to call function like getlatestmsg+userid

Comment: Using var as a variable name, really?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your functions are declared in the global scope, they become attributes on the window object. Therefore the following can be accessed via window.getlatestmsg123, and using [] notation window['getlatestmsg123'];

```
function getlatestmsg123() {
}
```

Therefore you can assess your functions using

```
window["getlatestmsg"+userid];
```

and you can call it using

```
window["getlatestmsg"+userid](userid, username);
```

However I'd recommend against this approach, your design appears to be broken. I'd have one function that dealt with any user instead.